I would love to build an IRC but can't
I have looked at the wiki and tried to build an IRC but want to build an IRC but cannot.
wiki URL :Run your own IRC server
“. /inspircd start” This command does not work.
“ERROR: Cannot open config file: /workspaces/IRC/inspircd-2.0.25/run/conf/inspircd.conf
Exiting...” and the CLI log comes back.
I myself do not have an environment and run it on github-codespace.
Images for which .conf exists
pictures for which .cof exists -2
ubontu version -20.04
"i am japanese 　good day!"

Github link (https://github.com/kkk2z/IRC)
